# GitExtensions show only master branch in "branches" drop down

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-extensions

I am using GitExtensions as a UI sidekick of Git command line and I am facing a problem with it. Everything is fine with it except one thing: the drop down where it is supposed to show all the existing branches, it shows only master branch. In reality, if I go to Git bash and do a git branch then it will show me multiple branches which are active but this one will not. Contrary to how mine is working, all my colleagues can see the entire list of all the branch available to them

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the difference between your machine and your fellow colleagues machines are, but what I can say is that the dropdown in Git Extensions (the one that by default is located between the repository dropdown and the stash button in the menubar) will only show you the branches that you have available locally along with an option in the bottom to check out some other branch ("Checkout branch    Ctrl+.").

Selecting the bottom-most option ("Checkout branch") will give you a dialog where you can select which branch you wish to check out. By default this one will also only show you the branches you have available locally, but now you can select the radio button for "Remote branch". The dropdown below that radio button will now show you **all** branches available on the remote repository (most likely called "origin"). Select the branch you're interested in and leave the rest of the textboxes and click "Checkout". Now you should be all set to work with the newly created local branch based on the remote branch you wanted to work with.